# Can't upgrade raid 1 array from 256GB to 2TB disks

Tags: 20.04, raid

I am running ubuntu 20.04 with 2 256GB Samsung EVO SSD disks connected via USB3 SATA adaptors. They are configured as raid 1. The array does not contain the operating system, but contains a number of logical partition that are used as LUNS with targetcli. Everything is working fine but I am out of space.

I have now purchased 2 2TB Samsung EVO SSD disks. The same disks but bigger. However my raid array keeps failing. At first I thought the disks were faulty so I returned them and replaced them but the behaviour persists.

It doesn't matter if I create the array at the disk or partition level. Once I have set up a lun and tried to connect to it the raid array fails. Sometimes it fails before I even touched it.

thinking it must still be the disks I swapped out to 2 2TB Crucial MX500 disks and I got exactly the same behaviour.

I have used the same command to create the array on both disk sizes, and from both manufactures.

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

Is there something I need to do differently because of the size of the disks, I can't find anything online.